# Get rid of moron view in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

So sometimes when I check out a project in Intellij it shows up like a normal IDE with my files on the right side so I can see them all. But sometimes it shows up in what i like to call moron view because all of the directories are stacked along the top and I can only open 1 file at a time and not see the entire structure. I am sure it serves a purpose but since I have used WebStorm for over a year and IntelliJ for almost three months I would assume that changing the project structure view would be a simple option... Anyone know how to change the view from moron to normal.

Change this:

[image: Moron view]

To this:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you missed one of the words you were trying to redact.

Comment: yeah I know. I'm ok with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your two screen shots show two different things: The Navigation Bar (screen shot 1) and the Project View (screen shot 2).

It looks like you have moved the Project View button to the top (the one with the IntelliJ IDEA icon). Drag and drop or right click it and select `Move To > Left`, to move it to the left side again. You will probably need to resize it and make it bigger, to see the Project file tree again.

After that, what you call the moron view, will still be visible. In IntelliJ IDEA it is called the Navigation bar. And it can be show and hidden via the View menu.

Comment: That I know. So how about moving the navigation bar to the side so that I can easily navigate the files?

Comment: That's not possible. You use the Project view for that (what I called Project button above, before I edited the answer).

Comment: ok. Then how do I get project view to list the files in the project?

Comment: That's what I am trying to communicate in the second paragraph of my answer, but English is not my native language....

Comment: @isaacweathers If you look closely to your 1st screenshot, you have the Project view button just below the navigation bar. Drag & drop it to the right, making it look like in your 2nd screenshot. You can easily identify the button by the IJ icon and the text `1:Project`. Also unless you changed the default keymap, CTRL + 1 should toggle its state so you can spot it right away.